# .lib error when I'm using a dll?

Tags: c++, windows, dll

I'm trying to get some practice using windows DLLs (not used to them). I followed this article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636(v=vs.80).aspx

To the letter.

And yet, I am receiving this error:

1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\debug\math.lib'

My project is a dll project, not a lib. And there are no libs created from my projects at all (the whole solution).

Anybody have any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Are you getting the link error on the DLL project or on the console application project?

Comment: The win32 project itself. I *think* it might be because not all of my class members are declared with the __declspec(dllimport) statement?

Comment: both projects are win32 projects.  Is it the .dll project or the .exe projet

Comment: The instructions say __declspec(dllexport)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

VS does not create an import library if dll does not actually export anything. To quickly check if that is your case, find your dll, open it with [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) and see if there are any exports at all.

If you find exports missing check if you did mark anything for export: either by declaring classes/functions as "__declspec( dllexport )" (when header is included in dll, dllimport when included by exe), or extern "C" plus module definition (.def) file.

Comment: For me the `__declspec(dllexport)` was the remedy for my problem. I hope this is still the state of the art solution in 2017

Answer (score 2):

Your .dll project could be creating an import .lib.  This simplifies using a DLL.  An import .lib is a simple library that has the same functions as your dll, but it doesn't have the implementation -- when you use it, it loads the dll and then forwards the calls you make to the dll.

Or, the console project might think you have an import .lib -- but you don't.

The instructions for creating/using a dll you have are a little odd.  I don't do it that way (with the Add References dialog).  You might need to look through your project settings and see if you see any reference to math.lib -- or anything about creating an import .lib.

Also, check your output directories on the .dll project and see if math.lib (or any .lib) was created.

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to something as simple as the **dependency** you might have added for your main project upon the DLL projects.

In visual studio 2008 the setting can be found at: `Project Dependencies` and simply un-checking the DLL projects will solve the problem.

Additionally you can verify that: the path to the DLL 'Lib's are no longer included in the 'linker' command-line of your main project at: `Configuration Properties > Linker > Command Line`